# Is there any method to do this layout, I tried it with flexbox without success

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I tried with flexbox but it was impossible.

[image]

the best I can do is put the boxes in a column and using order move the "b" from place to place, but I can't get the last element to jump from the column

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Not possible with flexbox or Css-grid. Float might work though.

Comment: Can you update with html and css that you got currently?

Comment: @Paulie_D I made an answer using css-grid, I'm not used to it so I'm not sure it's the best way, but the result seems to be what it's asked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it because I'm not use to css grids, but you can make 2 different grid templates to get the result below :

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
    "a" 
    "b" 
    "c" 
    "d" / 100%;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#a {
  grid-area: a;
}

#b {
  grid-area: b;
  /*height: 30px;*/
  height: fit-content;
}

#c {
  grid-area: c;
}

#d {
  grid-area: d;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    grid-template: 
      "a b"  
      "c b"  
      "d b" / 25% 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B<br>B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
  <div id="d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite. If you look at the desired result, the right column is not supposed to be the same height as the left.

Comment: Then you can set an height like `height:fit-content;`

Comment: No you cannot. Try it.

Comment: I did and [it seems to work](https://i.imgur.com/uVoTD7H.png) on chrome and firefox